# Corrupt BIOS hw-PMU resources CentOS 7 Hp Proliant 310 but boots successfully

Tags: centos, boot, bios, corruption

I just installed CentOS 7 on my HP Proliant 310 Gen8 Server. Everything looks fine, except the line of corrupt BIOS when CentOS is booting `[Firmware Bug] The BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)`.
What surprise me is, the **successful** boot after this message and the normal use possible of the server.
Did I miss something for the installation or can I ignore it?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer in an [HP Enterprise Forum](https://community.hpe.com/t5/proliant-servers-ml-dl-sl/ml350-g9-bios-has-corrupted-hw-pmu-resources-msr-38d-is-330/m-p/6831422/highlight/true#M152674):

> Re: ML350 G9 BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)

> ```
>  [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)
> ```

This is caused by the ROM using performance counters Linux also wants to use. Linus doesn't like the hardware using any of these counters, so he marks it as a bug. It's just a message and doesn't have any impact on the system or the operation of the OS.

> ```
> i8042: Can't read the CTR while initializing i8042
> ```

> This message is from the kernel as it tries to load a driver for hardware that doesn't exist. The i8042 is for the PS2 keyboard/mouse which Gen9 doesn't have. Again an erroneous message.